# SIMULINK Model Configuration Reference Finds Error in Advisory Checks

Tags: matlab, configuration, reference, simulink

I was under the impression that if you use a configuration reference set to you main model and referenced subsystems, all will be affected. However, it is breaking my code generation advisor checks. This is the image I am getting:

[image]

Is this normal? I thought it should work as usual as the individual settings. Is it because it cannot distinguish between a config reference or a single config file?

The way I have propagated the config reference to all the models is by opening Model Explorer > Reference > Propagate to Referenced Models.